# Парсинг отдельных элементов на веб-страницы Python

Tags: python, парсер

Здравствуйте помогите пожалуйста решить задачу :
 [Вот сайт](https://www.euro-jackpot.net/ru/arhiv-rezultatov-2019)
с него мне нужно взять все цифры которые выпадали в 2019 году желательно по порядку [[7,12,28,34,45][12,20,21,22,35][25,31,38,49,50]]
помогите исправить код чтобы программа выполняла данное действие:
Немного точности к вопросу:

```
 <ul class="balls small">
                                <li class="ball"><span>7</span></li>
                                <li class="ball"><span>12</span></li>
                                <li class="ball"><span>28</span></li>
                                <li class="ball"><span>34</span></li>
                                <li class="ball"><span>45</span></li>
                                <li class="euro"><span>3</span></li>
                                <li class="euro"><span>6</span></li>
```

мне нужно было сделать чтобы программа с  `<ul class="balls small">`

брала каждое значение `<li class="ball"><span>---</span></li>` по порядку.
Задание решено пример в самом низу.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('https://www.euro-jackpot.net/ru/arhiv-rezultatov-2019')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select('.balls'):
    title = el.select('.ball ')
    print(title[0].text)
```

Задача решена таким образом:

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('https://www.euro-jackpot.net/ru/arhiv-rezultatov-2019')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for ultag in html.find_all('ul', {'class': 'balls small'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        print(litag.text)
```

Comment: Здравствуй, обычно в вопросе дополнительно пишут, какие способы пробовали и что не получалось. Добавь их, так всем будет проще тебе помочь

Comment: Здравствуйте , спасибо за коментарий , в следуший раз буду более точнее задавать вопрос!) я решил задачу таким образом.
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('https://www.euro-jackpot.net/ru/arhiv-rezultatov-2019')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for ultag in html.find_all('ul', {'class': 'balls small'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        print(litag.text)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r = requests.get('https://www.euro-jackpot.net/ru/arhiv-rezultatov-2019')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for ultag in html.find_all('ul', {'class': 'balls small'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        print(litag.text)
```